# Proving Holder's inequality for sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I want to prove the Holder's inequality for sums:

> Let $p\ge1$
>     be a real number. Let $(x_{k})\in l_{p}$
>     and $(y_{k})\in l_{q}$
>    . Then,
>   $$\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{k}y_{k}\vert\le\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{k}\vert^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert y_{k}\vert^{q}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$
>   with $q\in\mathbb{R}$
>     such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$
>    .

Inspired by a proof I've seen before, I attempted at a solution. I would like you to confirm the ideas and to answer the questions, which correspond to steps of the proof I don't know how to justify.

**My attempt:** Let $p>1$
  be a real number. $Let (x_{k})\in l_{p}$
  and $(y_{k})\in l_{q}$
 .

If $\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{k}\vert^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=0$
  or $\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert y_{k}\vert^{q}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}=0$
  the inequality is trivially true (*Question1: Is it? Why?*)

In case both are nonzero, we can define the sequences $(z_{k})$
  and $(w_{k})$
  with

$$z_{k}=\frac{x_{k}}{\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{k}\vert^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}}\ \text{ and }\ w_{k}=\frac{y_{k}}{\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert y_{k}\vert^{q}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}}$$

Now, $$\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert z_{k}w_{k}\vert\le\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\left(\frac{\vert z_{k}\vert^{p}}{p}+\frac{\vert w_{k}\vert^{q}}{q}\right)$$
  (by Young's Inequality).

But $$\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\left(\frac{\vert z_{k}\vert^{p}}{p}+\frac{\vert w_{k}\vert^{q}}{q}\right)=\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\left(\frac{\vert x_{k}\vert^{p}}{p\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{k}\vert^{p}\right)}+\frac{\vert y_{k}\vert^{q}}{q\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert y_{k}\vert^{q}\right)}\right)\le1$$
 (*Question2: Is this last inequality true? Why? If it is, the result follows smoothly...*)

So $\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert z_{k}w_{k}\vert\le1$
 . Multiplying both sides by the (positive) term $\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{k}\vert^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\cdot\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert y_{k}\vert^{q}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$
 , it's done. $\square$

Comment: You actually have inequality since $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}=1$. By your construction, the $l^p$ norm of $z=(z_k)$ and $l^q$ norm of $w=(w_k)$ are both 1.

Comment: Note the first trivially true thing happens because $\sum_n^\infty |x_n|^p$ means that $x_n$ must identically zero (just consider what an infinite sums means, and see how if any $x_n\neq 0$ this will be positive).

Comment: @CheeHan because $$\overset{\infty}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\vert z_{l}\vert^{p}=\overset{\infty}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\frac{\vert x_{l}\vert}{\Big\vert\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{k}\vert^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\Big\vert}=\frac{\overset{\infty}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{l}\vert}{\Big\vert\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{k}\vert^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\Big\vert}=1$$
  and similarly $$\overset{\infty}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\vert w_{l}\vert^{q}=1
 $$
Right?

Comment: @Simoes Yes, but of course that is assuming that $(x_k), (y_k)$ are not identically zero sequences.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For completeness I'll leave here my complete proof, using the suggestions in the comments.

**Proof:** Let $p>1$
  be a real number. $Let (x_{k})\in l_{p}$
  and $(y_{k})\in l_{q}$
 .

If $\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{k}\vert^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=0$
  or $\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert y_{k}\vert^{q}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}=0$
  the inequality is true: This is equivalent to $\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{k}\vert^{p}=0$
  or $\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert y_{k}\vert^{q}=0$
 , and, if any term of one of these series is nonzero, the series would be nonzero (because all terms are zero or positive), so $\vert x_{k}\vert^{p}=0$
  or $\vert y_{k}\vert^{q}=0$
  for all $k$
 . Hence, $\vert x_{k}\vert^{p}\vert y_{k}\vert^{q}=0$
  for all $k$.

In case both are nonzero, we can define the sequences $(z_{k})$
  and $(w_{k})$
  with

$$z_{k}=\frac{x_{k}}{\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{l}\vert^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}}\ \text{ and }\ w_{k}=\frac{y_{k}}{\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\vert y_{l}\vert^{q}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}}.$$

Now, $$\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert z_{k}w_{k}\vert\le\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\left(\frac{\vert z_{k}\vert^{p}}{p}+\frac{\vert w_{k}\vert^{q}}{q}\right)$$
  by Young's Inequality.

But $$\overset{\infty}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\vert z_{l}\vert^{p}=\overset{\infty}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\frac{\vert x_{l}\vert^p}{\Big\vert\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{k}\vert^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\Big\vert^p}=\frac{\overset{\infty}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{l}\vert^p}{\Big\vert\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{k}\vert^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\Big\vert^p}=1$$
  and similarly $$\overset{\infty}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\vert w_{l}\vert^{q}=1.$$

Hence $$\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\left(\frac{\vert z_{k}\vert^{p}}{p}+\frac{\vert w_{k}\vert^{q}}{q}\right)=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1.$$

So $\overset{\infty}{\underset{k=1}{\sum}}\vert z_{k}w_{k}\vert\le1$
 . Multiplying both sides by the (positive) term $\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{l}\vert^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\cdot\left(\overset{\infty}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\vert y_{l}\vert^{q}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$
 , it's done. $\square$

Comment: For completeness, let me just remark that the result for $p=\infty$ is also true with Holder conjugate $q=1$, and the proof is much simpler,

$$ \sum_n |a_n b_n | \le \|b\|_{\infty} \sum_n |a_n| = \|b\|_{\infty} \|a\|_1$$